# jQuery selector .not() NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a jQuery selector for a function which looks like this:

```
    $('html').not('.table-main tr[selected]').mousedown( function( e ) {
```

But somehow it is not filtering at all and i do not quite understand why.
Even if i just leave **('.table-main')** for the selector i still trigger the function when clicking into the table... What is wrong with that?

Using **document** or **'body'** instead of **'html'** does not help, as document is not triggering at all with .not() and 'body' results in the same.

Edit:
Just tried using another block outside of the table and it works. Is there a chance i cannot use this on tables?

Update2: As requested, here is the rendered html code of the table:

```
    <table border="0" cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="5px" class="table-main">
      <tr id="tablefields">
        <th style="padding: 0;">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
            <tr><th><div class="tr-head-get" id="tr-get-0">Name</div></th></tr>
            <tr><th><div class="th-header" id="th-header-0" style="top: 54px;">Name</div></th></tr>
          </table>
        </th>    
      <th style="padding: 0;"></th>
    </tr>
      <tr id='table_form_new_device' class='table_form_class'>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/devices" class="new_device" data-remote="true" id="new_device" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="T2dSeZpxxvgJdTP+yoE7BrVODzqJ95gyVu9Wh/v7oP8=" /></div>
        <th class='tablefield'>
          <input id="device_devicename" name="device[devicename]" size="10" type="text" />
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class='submitbox' id='submitbox_new_device'>S</div>
          <script>
            $('#submitbox_new_device').click(function (event) {
              $('#new_device').submit();
            });
          </script>
        </th>
    </form></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="dropdown-button" style="margin: 0 2px;">Filter</div>
```

Comment: Also it can be event bubbling problem. Read more about events order http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: So you're trying to select every tr that is not selected? Take a look at the [jQuery documentation for the "selected" selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). Your syntax looks a bit off. Some DOM examples would be helpful in aiding you more however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really, really want to use delegated event handling for this because you don't want to attach an event handler to every single element in the document.  You want to intercept bubbled events at the document level and just check if the mousedown came from an element that was not a selected row in your table.

In addition the `tr[selected]` seems unlikely to work.  I think you need to add a class `"selected"` to the selected row and then use `tr.selected` as the selector.

If you make that change, I'd suggest something like one of these two options:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.table-main tr.selected')) {
       // mouse down and it wasn't in a selected row of your table)
    }
})
```

You may also be able to let jQuery delegation do more of the work:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', ':not(.table-main tr.selected)', function() {
   // mouse down and it wasn't in a selected row of your table)

});
```

---

After seeing your actual HTML, if I understand the problem correctly, this should work.  This will give you an event anytime a click happens as long as that click is not in a row of `table-main` that has the `selected` class on it:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
   // mouse down and it wasn't in a selected row of your table)
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".table-main tr.selected").length) {
        console.log("mousedown not in selected row of table-main")
    }
});​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5QD6N/

Comment: This actually works (dunno why) if i use **.table-main** only and click in the spacing between the cells. Not if i click on the cells directly. Do i have to assign every single class inside the table to the selector aswell?

Comment: Add your actual HTML for the table to your question and we can help more specifically.  You will also need to be more specific about exactly which clicks you do and don't want processed in this handler.  This uses event bubbling and event delegation to solve the problem elegantly.  Also, which one of the two options did you try?

Comment: Posted the rendered html in shorter form since the real table is like 5 miles long

Comment: In that HTML, exactly which clicks do you want and not want in this event handler?

Comment: Lets say i want the selector on everything apart from 'table_form_class selected' to trigger the function

Comment: @NikoM. - I added a new version to my answer.  If this isn't exactly what you wanted, you should be able to tweak the selector as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[selected]` makes no sense on a element of type `tr`. You use selected for inputs(`checkbox,radio`). You can add a class `.selected` to the tr elements in `.table-main` and then use :

Edit: Like somebody posted above, you want to use select the elements nested inside the body.

```
$('body').find(':not(.selected)').mousedown(function(e){})
```

Comment: Actually it was supposed to be a boolean assigned via .data() but i guess it was incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1):

`$('html')` creates a jQuery object containing your HTML element.

`.not('.table-main tr[selected]')` removes any TR elements with a selected attribute (there is an error here, that attribute doesn't appear on TRs) that are descended from elements that are members of the `table-main` class. Since HTML elements are not TR elements and can't be descended from anything, this removes no elements and has no effects.

`mousedown( function( e )` binds an event handler to the HTML element. Unless something stops propagation, any click will eventually bubble up to there.

I'm *guessing* (since you didn't actually say what you wanted to achieve) that you want to capture clicks on TR elements that aren't selected. Assuming that you switch to using classes to make the HTML valid…

```
$('.table-main tr:not(.selected)').mousedown(…);
```

and

```
<tr class="selected">
```

Comment: I wanted to call the event on mousedown everywhere aside from this only table-row. [selected] was supposed to be a boolean assigned to the row via .data().
To simplify things i can take the table only, but it is not working.
Using $('html:not(.table-main)') is still reacting on .table-main